# check condition before submitting form in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I am submitting a frm that is basically an invoice of purchase. before submitting the form i want to implement the check that the user doesn't enter amount more than the total bill in the text box.for example if total bill is 300 and in the "paid amount" text box user enters 3000 accidentally then it should show the error message here is my code:

```
$("#mainform").submit(function() {
var total = $("#gtotal").val();
var paid  = $("#paid").val();
alert(paid);
alert(total);
if(paid > total)
{ 

alert("Amount can't be greater than total");

return false;
}
return true;

});
```

when I alert paid and total amount they show correct values, but the if condition is not working some times it submits the form if the condition is not fulfilled sometimes i doesn't even condition is fulfilled

Comment: is your input only accepting numbers?

Comment: when paid is more than total, you don't want to submit right?

Comment: Try to parse the variables total and paid in a number format with `parseInt` or `parseFloat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it may work:

```
var total = parseInt($("#gtotal").val());
var paid  = parseInt($("#paid").val());
```

Answer (score 1):

.val() returns strings

Convert paid and total to float with **parseFloat**, check them with **isNaN**, then compare. Like so:

```
paid = parseFloat(paid);
total = parseFloat(total);
if (!isNaN(paid) && !isNaN(total)) {
    if (paid > total) {
       ...
```

If you aren't using decimals you may use **parseInt**

Answer (score 1):

Add a parameter on submit function and call preventDefault method to avoid form to be submitted.

```
.submit(function(event) {
   ...
if (paid > total) {
   ...
   event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some conditions missed:

- empty input field
- not a number

In order to convert a string to number you can prefix the string with a plus sign.

A solution could be:

```js
$("#mainform").on('submit', function(e) {
    var total = +$("#gtotal").val();
    var paid  = +$("#paid").val();
    if (($("#gtotal").val().trim().length == 0) || isNaN(total)) {
        console.log("Please specify total");
        $("#gtotal").focus();
        e.preventDefault();
        //
        // stop function execution....
        //
        return;
    }
    if (($("#paid").val().trim().length == 0) || isNaN(paid)) {
        console.log("Please specify paid");
        $("#paid").focus();
        e.preventDefault();
         //
        // stop function execution....
        //
        return;
    }
    if(paid > total) {
        console.log("Amount can't be greater than total");
        //
        // prevent the submit action
        //
        re.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form id="mainform" action="http://www.google.com">
    gtotal: <input id="gtotal" type="text">
    paid:<input id="paid" type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form">
</form>
```